# How to create spaces between characters only for acronysms in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to add spaces between characters only for acronyms (all consecutive all-caps words) in Python.

**INPUT:**

```
"The PNUD, UN, UCALP and USA and U N."
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
"The P N U D, U N, U C A L P and U S A and U N."
```

I have this solution so far, but I am looking for something more efficient/elegant:

```
import re
data = "The PNUD, UN, UCALP and USA and U N."
result = re.sub(r'(?=(?!^)[^[a-z]|\s+|\W]*)', ' ', data)
result = re.sub(r'\s+(\W)', '\g<1>', result)
print(result)
```

Comment: regex is pretty efficient as is. Can't really do much better imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution `re.sub` with lambda function:

```py
import re

data = "The PNUD, UN, UCALP and USA and U N."

result = re.sub(r"\b[A-Z]{2,}\b", lambda g: " ".join(g.group(0)), data)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
The P N U D, U N, U C A L P and U S A and U N.
```

---

EDIT: Small benchmark

```py
import re
import regex
from timeit import timeit


pat1 = re.compile(r"\b[A-Z]{2,}\b")
pat2 = re.compile(r"([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])")
pat3 = re.compile(r"[A-Z](?=[A-Z])")  # the same without capturing group

# using regex module instead of re
pat4 = regex.compile(r"\b[[:upper:]]{2,}\b")


data = "The PNUD, UN, UCALP and USA and U N."


def fn1():
    return pat1.sub(lambda g: " ".join(g.group(0)), data)


def fn2():
    return pat2.sub(r"\g<1> ", data)


def fn3():
    return pat3.sub(r"\g<0> ", data)


def fn4():
    return pat4.sub(lambda g: " ".join(g.group(0)), data)


t1 = timeit(fn1, number=10_000)
t2 = timeit(fn2, number=10_000)
t3 = timeit(fn3, number=10_000)
t4 = timeit(fn4, number=10_000)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
print(t4)
```

Prints:

```
0.03805400081910193
0.10581987909972668
0.10386284696869552
0.044628452975302935
```

Comment: Lambda is faster. Thank you. Using regex instead of re is slightly slower but allows you to match also Unicode chars from non-English languages. Try regex.compile(r"\b[[:upper:]]+\b")

Comment: @EstebanGorupicz I've added `regex` module to the benchmark.

Comment: Loved your comprehensive propaedeutic approach.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following regex is a lot more trivial solution for this problem

```py
re.sub('([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])', '\\1 ', s)
```

I'm just using a positive lookahead and a backreference.

Comment: how about using regex to include non-english uppercase chars? 
regex.subf(r'([[:upper:]])(?=[[:upper:]])', '{1} ', data)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single call to re.sub and match a single uppercase char and assert another one to the right.

In the replacement use the match followed by a space using `\g<0>`

```
[A-Z](?=[A-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SLF96F/1)

Example

```
result = re.sub('[A-Z](?=[A-Z])', r'\g<0> ', data)
```

Comment: I tried this against the answer with capturing group and it performs the same (I'd expect it will be faster)...

Comment: @AndrejKesely In that case, not having to capture data would be the only advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Using Lambda with regex instead of re is slightly slower but allows you to match also Unicode chars from non-English languages, which is caeteris paribus a more generalizable answer.

```
import re
import regex
from timeit import timeit

pat1 = re.compile(r"\b[A-Z]+\b")
pat2 = re.compile(r"([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])")
pat3 = regex.compile(r"\b[[:upper:]]+\b")

data = "The PNUD, UN, UCALP and USA and U N."

def fn1():
    return pat1.sub(lambda g: " ".join(g.group(0)), data)

def fn2():
    return pat2.sub(r"\g<1> ", data)

def fn3():
    return pat3.sub(lambda g: " ".join(g.group(0)), data)


t1 = timeit(fn1, number=10_000)
t2 = timeit(fn2, number=10_000)
t3 = timeit(fn3, number=10_000)

print(fn1())
print(fn2())
print(fn3())
print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

[DEMO](https://tio.run/##lVDBaoQwFLznKx45JdSKmpvUFmmPRRZaL91dllija1ljSCO0X29jXNLtemogZIaZN@/lqW9zHCSbpq5XgzagBfKoFV@o0UMPputFZ@AsLAwhpLiJIbPG8H3oVXcSRONdtc1v3/Y3uwrT2ZBcG4jTKXnIFrDYmLPZhn@jtumolNDp/hxoT80Nt2b8ehSwKcqnAMrC3sf8eQNc1lC@5MsLRYhnv2igkTGhKQJ7tDCjljCPHn6OFTnxvqo5tClgwOHH0EnShq0eRkUiSgOY21Efk6xjEhdjp23v4nvA1xVsXcH@1diteFk5sf8IQI59JXQWR4coiihyG/Z6stbZpc5WOlK6ky6aUOpJcknYLzGxR4lHjE7TDw)